# write() syscall on LUKS partitions

Tags: operating-systems, luks

To my understanding, when the [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall is called, it writes the data to the OS buffer then returns. My question, in LUKS partition context, are:

1. Does [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) encrypt data then write to OS buffer then returns? OR, it just writes the raw data then returns, and only when the OS flushes its buffer to disk is the data encrypted?
2. What if after calling [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [`fsync()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) is also called?
3. How can I verify the exact behavior?

Having been searching on Google for a while but no result thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be answered mostly by looking at the position where LUKS is inserted in the entire stack. It is built on top of the Linux device-mapper subsystem (via dm-crypt), which works at the 'block device' level underneath the filesystem; unlocking a LUKS volume creates a virtual `/dev/dm*` device from which a filesystem is then mounted.

The inner operations of a block device (in this case the virtual DM device, whether it's a dm-crypt device, or a dm-raid device, or anything else) are completely invisible to the filesystem or to the VFS layer. Therefore, all buffers managed by the filesystem (or by VFS) contain only raw data; it is not encrypted at write() time as the subsystem is not aware of any encryption being in use.

When you `sync`, the filesystem buffers containing raw data are written to the underlying block device, which (if it's a dm-crypt device) will encrypt each block and forward the now-encrypted writes through to the underlying physical partition.

Buffers corresponding to the physical disk device contain encrypted data, as it only receives encrypted writes from the dm-crypt layer above it.

(Contrast this with 'fscrypt', which *is* built into the filesystem.)